# actionPerformed does not run for timer

Tags: java, timer, action, actionlistener, swingx

I am currently trying to write a code that involves a text doc of 1s, 0s, a 2 and 3 to act as a maze, 2 being the start and 3 the end, and use a timer and a search method to solve said maze. Currently my program will start and display the maze correctly, but it will not solve the maze. I ran a debug and it will go to the class TimerListener, but not the method actionPerformed, and I cannot figure out why. Here is a copy of my code:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class homework11and12 extends JFrame {
    private final int width = 1000;
    private final int height = 700;
    private JFrame frame;
    private DrawComponent component;
    private JPanel panel;
    private final int exitBlock = 3;
    private final int charBlock = 2;
    private final int emptyBlock = 0;
    private final int wallBlock = 1;
    private final int visitedBlock = 4;
    private final int moveRight = 5;
    private final int moveDown = 6;
    private final int moveUp = 7;
    private final int moveLeft = 8;
    private int[][] maze;
    private static int startX = 0;
    private static int startY = 0;
    private ActionListener listener;

    public homework11and12() {
        this.setSize(width, height + 100);
        maze = new int[7][10];
        loadMaze("test", maze);
        this.component = new DrawComponent(maze);
        this.add(this.component);
        listener = new TimerListener();
        final int DELAY = 100;
        Timer t = new Timer(DELAY, listener);
        t.start();
    }

    public JPanel addPanel() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        component = new DrawComponent(maze);
        panel.add(component);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void loadMaze(String filename, int[][] maze)  {
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
            int y = 0;
            while(y < 7) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    try {
                        maze[y][x] = in.nextInt();
                        if( maze[y][x] == 2) {
                            startX = x;
                            startY = y;
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }   
                y++;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in finding file.");
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> findSolution(int[][] board,int posx, int posy) {  
        ArrayList<Integer> moveList = null;
        if(posx+1<width) {
            if(board[posy][posx] == exitBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
                moveList.add(moveRight);
                repaint();
                return moveList;
            }
            else if (board[posy][posx] == emptyBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveRight);
                repaint();
                int[][] newBoard = arrayCopy(board);
                newBoard[posy][posx+1] = visitedBlock;
                ArrayList<Integer> result = findSolution(newBoard, posx+1, posy);
                if (result == null) {
                    moveList = null;
                }
                else {
                    moveList.addAll(result);
                    return moveList;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (posy + 1< height) {
            if(board[posy][posx] == exitBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveDown);
                repaint();
                return moveList;
            }
            else if (board[posy+1][posx] == emptyBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveDown);
                repaint();
                int[][] newBoard = arrayCopy(board);
                newBoard[posy+1][posx] = visitedBlock;
                ArrayList<Integer> result = findSolution(newBoard, posx, posy + 1);   
                if (result == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    moveList.addAll(result);
                    return moveList;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(posy - 1 >= 0) {
            if(board[posy-1][posx] == exitBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveDown);
                repaint();
                return moveList;
            }
            else if (board[posy-1][posx] == emptyBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveDown);
                repaint();
                int[][] newBoard = arrayCopy(board);
                newBoard[posy-1][posx] = visitedBlock;
                ArrayList<Integer> result = findSolution(newBoard, posx, posy-1);
                if (result == null) {
                    return result;
                }
                else {
                    moveList.addAll(result);
                    return moveList;
               }
            }
        }
        else if(posx - 1 >= 0) {
            if(board[posy][posx-1] == exitBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveLeft);
                repaint();
                return moveList;
            }
            else if(board[posy][posx-1] == emptyBlock) {
                moveList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                moveList.add(moveLeft);
                repaint();
                int[][] newBoard = arrayCopy(board);
                newBoard[posy][posx - 1] = visitedBlock;
                ArrayList<Integer> result = findSolution(newBoard, posx-1, posy);
                if (result == null) {
                    moveList = null;
                }
                else {
                    moveList.addAll(result);
                    return moveList;
               }
            }
        }
        return moveList;
    }

    private int[][] arrayCopy(int[][] array) {
        if(array == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][];
        for(int r = 0; r <array.length; r++) {
            newArray[r] = array[r].clone();
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    class DrawComponent extends JComponent {
        private int[][] maze;
        private DrawComponent(int[][] maze) {
            this.maze = maze;
        }
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int y = 0;
            while (y < 7) {
                 for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    if (maze[y][x] == 1) {
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.fillRect(x * 100,  y* 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                    else if(maze[y][x] == 2) {
                        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                        g.fillRect(x * 100, y * 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                    else if(maze[y][x] == 3) {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.fillRect(x * 100, y * 100, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
        class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                findSolution(maze, startX, startY);
            }
    }
}
```

The class TimerListener is at the complete bottom of the code. Is it a problem with where I start the timer? A few questions that were already answered were similar and said the problem was the timer never got to start, but I'm almost positive my timer is starting.

Edit: Here is my main() method

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class homeworkTest extends homework11and12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        homework11and12 test = new homework11and12();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setVisible(true);
        test.setTitle("Maze");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Giving us the main() method would help a lot.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos I added it

Comment: The timer works fine. The problem i think is that you must define better (or at least you don't explain it to us) what do you mean by "solving the maze". Also, why would you like to use a timer in order to solve the maze. Let's say that your findSolution() method works fine, and "finds" the solution (whatever this solution is). Why you must do it over and over again by using timer? Should the maze be solved only one time?

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos going thru findSolution should paint the JFrame so that it looks as if a color block is traveling thru the maze, but the JFrame never gets repainted.

Comment: Well you don't use component.repaint() method anywhere.

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos I had repaint called in one part of my findSolution() but not the other three. I just updated my code above and in eclipse, and it still will not repaint at all.